# Upgrade QEMU/KVM on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: ubuntu, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I am hoping this is the correct forum on which to introduce my question as I am new to Ubuntu/linux world... and KVM Hypervisor.

I am looking at upgrading the current version of KVM virtualisation tool which we use to create a small number of VMs including our Vsphere 6.0 server so as it is independent of our ESX farm.

The upgrade is necessary to mitigate some recent security vulnerabilities.

I am wondering what companion apps I have to upgrade at the same time as I upgrade KVM? I'm thinking about the virt tools (virt-manager etc), virsh. 
Does QEMU need to be upgraded independently as well? Or does it get updated when KVM is installed.

Does anyone have a plan of what they did when they have recently upgraded KVM that thye could forward to me?

The underlying Server hardware is Cisco UCS C220m4 (Standalone) - Ubuntu 16.10 (see attachment)

Thanks in advance

[Current KVM installs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDoI7.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I have been informed that 16.10 Ubuntu is no longer supported so will look at upgrading the OS version first.